# Is it possible to get form iD in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is it possible to find the formID in jquery file if i ddnt explicitly specify and id in razor view

`@using (Html.BeginForm())` Here i don't want to specify an id of th form and on click of a button i want to submit this form from my jquery file.

Here is my view and

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
```

This jquery doesnt work.

```
$(".TestCreateSubmit").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("submit");
    var form = this;//this doesnt work
    form.submit();  //this doesnt work
});
```

Is it possible to invoke the Submit() method of the form if id is not specified

This is my button in the form. This is the only button in this particular form:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
          <a class="btn btn-default TestCreateSubmit" href="#" role="button">Save</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
    public ActionResult TestCreate(Test test)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            //need to save the application using the Staff Manager Service here
            Test objTest  = DatabaseService.Test Create(test);

            if (objtest == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }


            return RedirectToAction("TestIndex");
        }


        return View(test);
    }`
```

Comment: Please add HTML also

Comment: try this $('form').submit().

Comment: Please note that only recent browsers guarantee a `click` event on the *first submit* button *if the form is submitted via a keyboard press*. That means you should be using the `submit` event instead.

Comment: Your script is selecting a class name, not an `id`. What is the element with `class="TestCreateSubmit"`? If its a button within the form tags, then you can use `var form = $(this).closest('form');`

Comment: @Shu ,@Stephen : Both the answers works fine. Is there any difference between these.

Comment: @Gone : I have tried these in Firefox and IE , it is working

Comment: @Jubi: Tested with latest IE versions only I would imagine. Your funeral :)

Comment: @jubi yes there is a difference.in my answer all the forms available in the DOM  will be submitted. I given that solution assuming only one form will be there in the DOM.In case of Stephen's answer only single form will be submitted, in which the button resides.

Comment: <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 text-right"><a class="btn btn-default TestCreateSubmit" href="#" role="button">Save</a></div>
        </div>  This is my button in the form . this is the only button in this particular form

Comment: As that is not a `submit` button, just an anchor link, you may be able to bypass the button by pressing `Enter` on any field in the form. Please try `Enter` in the text field and get back to us: https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/4tmz0xm5/

Comment: You have been given several "correct" answers (in comments) on how to get the *current* form, but as your button is actually a link and not a `type="submit"`, your code is easily bypassed by pressing Enter on an input field. Keyboard submission is the most common problem overlooked in form processing.

There are a couple of patterns for conditionally submitting forms, but all rely on the `submit` event and not click events. Please describe how your page is supposed to work (e.g. are you wanting to validate content?).

Comment: I just want to call one controller Post method. [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult TestCreate( Test  test){} I dont need to validate

Comment: So why the ajax link pretending to be a button? Pressing Enter on any text input will just submit the form normally. Just use a `type="submit"` button and style it to suit your UI needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been given several answers on how to get the *current* form like:

```
$(".TestCreateSubmit").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    form.submit();
});
```

but, as your button is actually a link and not a `type="submit"`, your code is easily bypassed by pressing Enter on an input field. e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/4tmz0xm5/ Keyboard submission is the most common problem overlooked in form processing.

There are a couple of patterns for conditionally submitting forms, but all rely on the `submit` event and not click events.

As you state you just want the link to submit the form normally, just change the link to an `input` with `type="submit"` and style it to look like whatever you need.

e.g.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
          <input class="btn btn-default TestCreateSubmit" type="submit" value="Save"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

You won't need any code at all then.

### Update to use Ajax:

From comment this was a test prior to using Ajax form submission. The steps for that are:

- Catch the form submit event
- Stop the default form submission (e.g. with `e.preventdefault()`)
- Get and serialise the form data
- Submit the form using [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) or [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

**Example:**

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);
    var data = $form.serialize();
    $.post(url, data);
})
```

Comment: yes, Make sense of using a button.Instead of complete form submit i want a partial submit using Ajax. I am not sure on how to make ajax calls. So i first tried with form submit to test my functionality and will implement ajax call.Now i need to make an ajax call to complete the functionality

Comment: $.Ajax form submission is very easy. You will need to catch the form `submit` event instead though. I will add a quick example.

Comment: Added basic example. If you need more than that I suggest asking a new question :)

Comment: This examples is very clear to understand. Thanks alot. The issue i have now is data is coming as empty

Comment: @jubi: You will need to shown your entire form HTML and server code. The field names must match the expected names in the controller. Use a tool like Fiddler2 to see what is being transmitted.

Comment: + Action result to the question

Comment: @jubi: Does the `Test` object contain exactly the same named fields as the form?

Comment: Yes.if i changed   var $form = $(this).closest('form'); i am getting the data . Another problem is its not calling the action result. The URL changed. But the post method is not executing

Comment: @jubi: use Fiddler2 to see what the HTTP response is. 404 means the URL is actually wrong (relative to wrong position?) or the parameters do not match at all.

Comment: You are right, the URL is wrong. By mistake i added TestController/TestCreate. I have removed the Controller and the URL now is Test/TestCreate...Thanks for pointing me themistake .. And you helped me to complete my first mvc page.

Comment: If you look at the action result after completing the save it has to be redirected to another action. When i used ajax call it didnt return to the page it still remains in the page where i have the Save button

Comment: @jubi: Ah. Another twist. Ajax does not support redirects *out-of-the-box* (and it is non-trivial to implement). What do you need to redirect back to?

Comment: Oh No!!!Redirect to the index page .Ajax call is to save the data to the database and once it added to the database there is a summary page where it will list the added record. That is what i called Index page.  Used this return RedirectToAction("TestIndex"); another action method

Comment: @jubi: Just redirect to the index using client-side javascript: e.g. `window.location="url"`. Ignore the server response as that is returning an page (no need now).

Comment: $.post(url, data).done(function()
        {
        window.location = "/" + TestController + "/TestIndex";
        }); Hope this is what you meant. Now my index page loads twice one from script and one from returning from the server

Comment: The one from the server should be removed as it is just thrown away. Get `TestCreate` to return an empty result (e.g. an empty string). e.g. `return new EmptyResult();`

Comment: You know, You have  done a great help. You are just amasing for quick response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103071/discussion-between-jubi-and-gone-coding-goodbye).